# ASP.NET Core MVC 6 Azure B2C Active Directory Authentication issue

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I followed the article : https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-b2c

In this sample app there is a Sign-in button. I am able to Sign-in successfully by clicking Sign-In button by providing my Azure B2C Tenant and registering the application in the tenant.

In another app, I want to authenticate without the Sign-In button being clicked i.e. right when I open the URL, I get redirected first to the Azure B2C AD login page, and after successful validation of credentials, I should be able to see the home screen.

So, what I did was from the URL mentioned from the article, I copied the SiginIn() method as:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    await SignIn();

    await GetDataAsync();
}
```

I get an error message on running the application as : **InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: b2c_1_org_b2c_global_signin**

Please advise how can I authenticate directly without the signin button. Previously with MVC5, I have successfully done this where I used **[Authorize]** attribute on the Controller class.

**Controller Code with Index method**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using WebViewerCore.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace WebViewerCore.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class DocumentController : Controller
    {
        #region GlobalVariables
        private static readonly string serviceUrl = "";
        private string doctype = string.Empty;
        private string dmsno = string.Empty;
        public string documentName = string.Empty;
        private string errMsg = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder msg;
        Document doc;
        private IHostingEnvironment _env;
        private IConfiguration _config;
        #endregion

        #region C'tor
        public DocumentController(IHostingEnvironment env, IConfiguration config)
        {
            _env = env;
            _config = config;
        }
        #endregion

        #region ControllerAction
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            //return View();
            try
            {
                //await SignIn();

                string storageAccount = _config.GetSection("BlobStorage").GetSection("StorageAccount").Value;
                string storageContainer = _config.GetSection("BlobStorage").GetSection("StorageContainer").Value;

                ViewBag.StorageAccount = storageAccount;
                ViewBag.StorageContainer = storageContainer;

                await GetDataAsync();

                //HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument";

                if (TempData["QueryStringMissing"] != null && (bool)TempData["QueryStringMissing"] || doc == null)
                {
                    return View("View");
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("Index", doc);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //logger.LogErrorWithMessage(ex, ex.StackTrace);
                //return View("Error", new HandleErrorInfo(ex, "Document", "Index"));
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

**Startup.cs code**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

namespace WebViewerCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        #region Global Variables
        public static string SignUpPolicyId;
        public static string SignInPolicyId;
        public static string ProfilePolicyId;
        public static string ClientId;
        public static string RedirectUri;
        public static string AadInstance;
        public static string Tenant;
        #endregion
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            //var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            //    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            //    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            //    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            //    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            //Configuration = builder.Build();

            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();

            // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache.
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
            });

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

            // Add Authentication services.
            services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions => sharedOptions.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Document}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            // App config settings
            ClientId = Configuration["AzureAD:ClientId"];
            AadInstance = Configuration["AzureAD:AadInstance"];
            Tenant = Configuration["AzureAD:Tenant"];
            RedirectUri = Configuration["AzureAD:RedirectUri"];

            // B2C policy identifiers
            SignUpPolicyId = Configuration["AzureAD:SignUpPolicyId"];
            SignInPolicyId = Configuration["AzureAD:SignInPolicyId"];

            // Configure the OWIN pipeline to use OpenID Connect auth.
            //app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpPolicyId));
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));
        }

        private OpenIdConnectOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
        {
            policy = policy.ToLower();
            return new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {
                // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
                // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
                MetadataAddress = string.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, policy),
                AuthenticationScheme = policy,
                CallbackPath = new PathString(string.Format("/{0}", policy)),

                // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from config.json
                ClientId = ClientId,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,
                Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnRemoteFailure = RemoteFailure,
                },
                ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,

                // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "name",
                }
            };
        }

        // Used for avoiding yellow-screen-of-death
        private Task RemoteFailure(FailureContext context)
        {
            context.HandleResponse();
            if (context.Failure is OpenIdConnectProtocolException && context.Failure.Message.Contains("access_denied"))
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            else
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("/Home/Error?message=" + context.Failure.Message);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To automatically redirect users navigating to a specific controller or endpoint in MVC, all you need to do is add the [Authorize] attribute, provided you've configured your middleware correctly.

In the case of Azure AD B2C, you need to make sure you add the OpenID Middleware like so:

```
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
            // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
            MetadataAddress = string.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, policy),
            AuthenticationScheme = policy,
            CallbackPath = new PathString(string.Format("/{0}", policy)),

            // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from config.json
            ClientId = ClientId,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRemoteFailure = RemoteFailure,
            },
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,

            // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
            },
        };);
```

The sample you referenced already does what you want, to a point.
In that sample, if you haven't signed in and navigate to /about, you'll get automatically redirected to Azure AD B2C to sign in.

As it stands, the sample has the [Authorize] attribute only on a controller action in the Home controller, you'll want to move that up to the controller level and add it to every controller. Then you can just remove the the sign-in/sign-up/sign-out buttons and controller action.

Comment: :Code I wrote referring to the example URL provided earlier by me is same as you provided.Using [Authorize] attribute, when I hit the controller's Index method, I get a blank page, no error in browser console. The application seems to be doing nothing in this case strangely. `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));` `private OpenIdConnectOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
        {
            policy = policy.ToLower();
            return new OpenIdConnectOptions
            {...}; } }`

Comment: Earlier I was using ControllerName as 'Home' in the route. Setting the route correctly as : `app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Document}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });`. Without `[Authorize]` attribute on Controller, my Index view opens, but when I use `[Authorize]` attribute on Controller, I get a blank page.

Comment: In Startup.cs file, using `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AutomaticChallenge = true
            });`, I get redirected to the url : https://localhost:44361/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F

Comment: Open developer tools in the browser (F12) to and see what's going on. What request is resulting in that blank page?

Comment: On using [Authorization] attribute on Controller, I get in browser console :  **HTTP401: DENIED - The resource required authentication.

GET - https://localhost:44361/**

Comment: Can you update your question with the code on Startup.cs, the controller, etc? Better there than in the comments.

Comment: Update questions (post) with Controller's Index method and complete StartUp.cs file's code.

Comment: You're missing app.UseCookieAuthentication(); right after app.UseStaticFiles();

Comment: I didn't find app.UseCookieAuthentication in Visual Studio 2017. I saw it was there in VS2017 RC.